# Replace a word in a specific line (allow users to choose which line they want to edit and the word they want to edit)

Tags: java

I've figured out how to let the users to replace the words in the text file. However, what if I want the user to replace a word in a text file for a specific line. For example:

```
Kent:23:Male:Chief
Jacob:25:Male:Plumber
```

I want the output to be like:

```
Kent:23:Female:Chief
Jacob:25:Male:Plumber
```

Instead of:

```
Kent:23:Female:Cheif
Jacob:25:Female:Plumber
```

My code so far:

```java
try {    
    File f = new File("bookingDetails.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
    StringBuilder bd = new StringBuilder();
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        bd.append(input.nextLine()+"\n");
    }
    String fileContents = bd.toString();
    input.close();
    String oldLine = jTextField3.getText();
    String newLine = jTextField1.getText();
    fileContents = fileContents.replace(oldLine,newLine);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    fw.append(fileContents);
    fw.flush();
} catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Comment: Load into `List<String>` with `Files.readAllLines`. Use the list for your edits. Save it to file again

Comment: Side note, this: `catch(Exception ex) {}`, is not a great idea. At least print out the exception's stack trace in the catch block so you'll know if some bad things are happening with your code.

Comment: You can consider turning your *de facto* csv file into java beans too

Comment: this is basically unrelated to swing - solve replacing words in the file without ui (use hard-coded replacement texts), only after having succeeded in that add ui

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change a particular word unless the user specifies which of the two identical words to change. However, if you want to change the first word in a string, the string.replaceFirst(oldLine, newLine) method can help.

I don't quite understand the problem in a general way, but in your specific case you could prompt the user to indicate the ordinal number of the word to be replaced.

For example like this:

```java
File f = new File("bookingDetails.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
StringBuilder bd = new StringBuilder();
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    bd.append(input.nextLine()+"\n");
}
String fileContents = bd.toString();
input.close();
String oldLine = jTextField3.getText();
String newLine = jTextField1.getText();

//Using the indexOf() method, we find out how many times the required string occurs
//in the text. All its occurrences are written to the List.
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int index = 0;
while(index != -1){
    index = fileContents.indexOf(oldLine, index);
    if (index != -1) {
        indexes.add(index);
        index++;
    }
}

//If there is more than one entry in the list,
//the user is prompted to enter which of the entries to replace
if (indexes.size() > 1) {
    //Opening a dialog box with a question. Specify the range of input values from
    //1 to the size of the list with entries
    String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Found multiple occurrences of the string '" + oldLine +
            "'. Specify the ordinal number from 1 to " + indexes.size() + ":",  
            "Replacement number", 
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    //Try-catch block, in which the program tries to convert the entered string into
    //a number. If it succeeded, program goes to further instructions in the
    //try block, if not, it goes to the catch block
    try {
        //Decreasing the resulting number by 1, since indexing in the list
        //starts from 0
        int number = Integer.parseInt(result) - 1;
        //If the user enters a number that does not fall within the range of the list,
        //a warning is displayed
        if (number < 0 || number > indexes.size() - 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "You entered the wrong number. All occurrences will be replaced.");
            fileContents = fileContents.replace(oldLine, newLine);
        }
        //Otherwise, we get the position of the string from the list and replace it.
        //Using the substring method, we get part of the string before the search word,
        //part of the string after the search word, and insert newLine between them
        else {
            int currentOccur = indexes.get(number);
            fileContents =
                fileContents.substring(0, currentOccur) +
                newLine +
                fileContents.substring(currentOccur + newLine.length() - 2);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "You entered the wrong number. All occurrences will be replaced.");
        fileContents = fileContents.replace(oldLine, newLine);
    }
}
else fileContents = fileContents.replace(oldLine, newLine);

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
fw.append(fileContents);
fw.flush();
```

However, this is not the best solution, if you want something more functional, you should reconsider your approach to the task and try to embed a full-fledged text editor in your user interface, such as **JTextArea**